# How do I access a value from a foreign key in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, foreign-keys

I have read all the related threads and have exhausted my research and nothing I do seems to work. I'll include the relevant code:

**models.py**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
  posted = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
  body = models.TextField(blank=True)
  category = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Category')
  images = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Image')

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.title

  @permalink
  def get_absolute_url(self):
      return ('teensite.myapp.views.view_post', None, {'slug': self.slug})

class Image(models.Model):

  def content_file_name(instance, filename):
      return os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, filename)

  title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
  number = models.IntegerField()
  image = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
  body = models.TextField(blank=True)
  citation = models.URLField(blank=True)
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      """Save image dimensions."""
      super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
      im = PImage.open(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.name))
      self.width, self.height = im.size
      super(Image, self).save(*args, ** kwargs)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.image.name

  def size(self):
      """Image size."""
      return "%s x %s" % (self.width, self.height)

  def get_absolute_url(self):
      return ('http://www.teensdigest.com/media/'+self.image.name)
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
  return render(request, 'home.html', {'cats': Category.objects.all(),
                                         'blogs' : reversed(Blog.objects.all()),
                                          })
```

**home.html**

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
  {% with blog.images_set.all|first as pic %}
      <div class="gal_grid_item" href="{{ blog.get_absolute_url }}">
      <a class="gal_grid_image_wrapper" href="{{ blog.get_absolute_url }}">
      <img class="gal_grid_image" src="{{ pic.get_absolute_url }}" />
      </a>
      <a class="gal_grid_info" href="{{ blog.get_absolute_url }}">
      <p class="gal_title text-center">{{ blog.title }}</p>
      </a>
      </div>
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

I need the home.html template to display the first image in blog.images. The problem is with {{ pic.get_absolute_url }} the rest of the template renders as expected but {{ pic.get_absolute_url }} returns no value. I have tried other methods of accessing other values inside the Image model and none of them work like {{ blog.images.all.0.title }} etc

Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `images` field in your `Blog` model has a `ForeignKey` relationship with `Image` but you are treating it as a `ManyToMany` relationship (judging by the `{% with blog.images_set.all ... %}` in your template).

Depending on how you are modelling the relationship, you can either change the `images` field from:

```
images = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Image')
```

to

```
images = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.Image')
```

migrate your database and then you can use

```
{% with blog.images.all ... %}
```

in your template. This would indicate that a blog can have multiple images and an image can belong to multiple blogs. Alternatively you can move the relationship to the `Image` model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
     ...
     blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
```

and use:

```
 {% with blog.image_set.all ... %}
```

in your template ([see reversing the relationships in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)). This would indicate that a blog can have multiple images, but an image only every belongs to one blog post.

Comment: Thank you, changing the relationship to ManyToMany worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Your model is broken. The way you have it, an Image can have multiple Blogs but a Blog can only have one Image. You want it the other way round, so the ForeignKey should be defined on the Blog model, pointing to Image. Then your template will work as it is.

One further note: please don't get all Blogs and then call `reversed` on them. That's horribly inefficient. Instead, get the db to return them in reverse order:

```
Blog.objects.all().reverse()
```

Even better, define a creation time field on the model and order by that.